# Switch loop and matching answers

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm trying to build a program to solve any question. Here's what I did:

```
data.content = "1. The word 'virile' means what?\na. Like a rabbit\nb. Like a man\nc. Like a wolf\nd. Like a horse\n" # I'm defining the question here.
```

Here's the code to know what the answer is for the question that we defined:

```
if (data.Content.Contains(question))
        {
            switch (question)
            {
                case "The word 'virile' means what?":
                    ans = " Like a man ";
                    break;
                case "is he a man ?":
                    ans = "No";
                    break;
                case "Can you speak ?":
                    ans = "hello";
                    break;
```

Now for the solving part:

```
var inputSplit = data.Content.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
theanswer = new string(inputSplit.Where(x => x.Contains(ans)).Select(x => x[0]).ToArray()[0], 1);
Reply(theanswer);
```

The problem is that it display's "null" as the answer because it won't go into switch loop. Any help?

Comment: We need to know what `data` is/looks like. Could you please post the code for it?

Comment: `data.content` and `data.Content` are two different things. make sure you're setting and getting the `content` correctly. Try to debug the program and check the content field before the if statement.

Comment: Check for whitespaces.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: it's not a "switch loop", it's a "switch block".

Comment: data.Content . it gets the question from the website .

Comment: @rami_ahmed ok, so what *type* is data when you receive it? an object?

Comment: @thesystem string

Comment: @rami_ahmed If it is already a string, you don't need to say `data.Content`, simply say `data = "1. The word ..."` etc. to assign your string to `data`. Then, in your if-else, say `if (data.Contains(...` - so leave out `.Content` if it's already a string.  I am pretty sure that you can't use `.Content` on a string.

Comment: ok , but why it give me null ? its not going in the switch because im defining the answer for each question

Comment: @rami_ahmed how have you defined `ans` and `question`? Show the whole defining of it.

Comment: And how is `question` filled?? And, most importantly: Did you use the debugger? It is your best friend and much more valuable than anything SO could offer! __Plus__: Where did the `1. ` go?

Comment: public string ans { get; set; }

Comment: @Taw its filled from (data.Content) which is coming from website ..

Comment: @rami_ahmed we can't see anywhere, that you assign `question` to `data.Content`. How does that look? We need to see every important part of the code :)

Comment: Please try to stay focused on SO. Also try to answer all questions posted to you. Where __did__ the `1. go`?

Comment: @rami_ahmed I can't talk right now, but if you update your question with everything of the code, then I will take a look at it! :)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pXBuRszb

Comment: @Taw its not big idea 1. i can remove it i just copy/pasted the hole question

Comment: Um, meanig what?? You absolutely need to post the real code. If you made an error, do corect it or else we all look at a ghost. Also we only asked for the assignment statemnt of `question`. Pastebin is yet another outside resource..

Comment: question = data.Content ; #From (data.Content i get the question)

Comment: @rami_ahmed ok, I have taken a look at the code. Lets say the case is "The word virile means what". What do you want to happen and be output?

Comment: @rami_ahmed I think I found your problem and made an answer. Look below to see it. I think it's because your property `ans` is `null`

Comment: The string start with  _"1. The word 'virile' means what?"_ but you compare to _"The word 'virile' means what?"_ A typo?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem, but it's too long to be a comment... I will delete if it's not the answer.

When you make a property like this: `public string ans { get; set; }`, you don't set it to anything, so `ans` is actually `null`.

This causes problem on your second last line: `theanswer = new string(inputSplit.Where(x => x.Contains(ans)).Select(x => x[0]).ToArray()[0], 1);`. In the middle of this line, you check if... `x.Contains(ans))`.

If you change `public string ans { get; set; }`, to `public string ans = ""`, it will never be `null` at any point.

I don't know if my explanation is entirely correct, but setting  `ans` to `""` instead of having it as a property made it work for me. Try it and report back if it doesn't work :)

Comment: it should go to the same case of the question to get the answer from it . but when i debug it . it skips the switch i dont know why

Comment: @rami_ahmed ok, I'm sorry to hear that. If it skips the switch, it's because your if-statement evaluates to false, meaning `data.Content` doesn't contain `question`. So I would assume `data.Content` is null. EDIT: If you can post how you receive `data`, then we can go from there.

Comment: @rami_ahmed EDIT: Either `data.Content` doesn't contain `question`, or  your cases don't match what `question` contains. You need a default switch-block that executes, if none of your cases match.

Comment: im really sorry for the late reply . data.Content when i debug it , it return true in the if-statement . maybe the problem as you said in the cases it self . although when i do it with if-else if statement . it works fine . :(

Comment: @rami_ahmed No worries for the late reply. If it returns true in the if-statement, and it works fine without the switch statement, then there is something wrong with the switch-statement and/or the cases! :-)

Comment: hello . i found the problem from the cases as you mention . how i can make it ignore the spaces  and the number of the question so the cases get matched easily

Comment: @rami_ahmed Sorry for late answer. Good to hear you found it. I am not entirely sure what you mean, could you elaborate on exactly what you want to happen?